# Loading an external url html

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have a button that goes to a page and that page generates a url to copy and paste.

Is there a way that I could load that page and access the html to parse out the url and go directly to that url?

I read on jQuery load and get functions and they do not support cross domain loads. I also thought I could maybe use an iFrame to load the document then use jQuery to parse the page that way, but salesforce doesn't load iFrames due to clickjacking.

Can anyone think of a way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this on the server-side in Apex providing you have created a [remote site setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&language=en) to allow access. To work with an apex:commandButton the code would look like this:

```
public PageReference redirectToParsedUrl() {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HTTPResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        String html = res.getBody();
        // Do your parsing
        String url = ...
        return new PageReference(url);
    } else {
        // Error handling
    }
}
```

or you could expose it as a WebService method and use a JavaScript button.